Removing a single function from exports with Vyper modules
I have a contract that imports a module with an interface with many functions.
from snekmate.tokens import erc721

How would I export all functions except 1?

exports: (
            erc721.owner, 
            erc721.balanceOf,
            erc721.ownerOf,
            erc721.getApproved,
            erc721.approve,
            erc721.setApprovalForAll,
            erc721.isApprovedForAll,
            erc721.transferFrom,
            erc721.safeTransferFrom,
            erc721.tokenURI, 
            erc721.totalSupply,
            erc721.totkenByIndex, 
            erc721.tokenOfOwnerByIndex,
            erc721.burn,
#            erc721.safe_mint, comment one out?
            erc721.set_minter,
            erc721.permit,
            erc721.DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
            erc721.transfer_ownership,
            erc721.renounce_ownership,
            erc721.name,
            erc721.symbol,
            erc721.isApprovedForAll,
            erc721.is_minter,
            erc721.nonces,
    )


You can optionally export interfaces:
exports: (
    erc721.IERC721, 
    erc721.IERC721Metadata, 
    erc721.IERC721Enumerable
)

This way, you can specify exactly what functions you want, without having to be incredibly verbose.
